# Gradle 6+ : compile groovy before kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on a project combining `groovy` and `kotlin`.
My Kotlin classes require objects from groovy part, how can i make gradle compile groovy before kotlin ?

I'm using `Gradle 6.3` with `kotlin-dsl`

I've tried several solutions : srcsets order, tasks order, ...
Nothing seems to work

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried what it says in the docs? https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sub:compile_deps_jvm_lang

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) ! (why this documentation doesn't come out on google )

Here is the adaptation of documentation for `kotlin` & `groovy`

```kotlin
tasks.named<AbstractCompile>("compileGroovy") {
    // Groovy only needs the declared dependencies
    // (and not longer the output of compileJava)
    classpath = sourceSets.main.get().compileClasspath
}

tasks.named<AbstractCompile>("compileKotlin") {
    // Java also depends on the result of Groovy compilation
    // (which automatically makes it depend of compileGroovy)
    classpath += files(sourceSets.main.get().withConvention(GroovySourceSet::class) { groovy }.classesDirectory)
}
```

Comment: I am strong in the ways of Google  have fun!

Comment: I though i was not that bad too ^^ but you're my master. Thanks again !